# Verify 4 numbers from a ticket

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a Lottery System where a Player submit 4 selected numbers.
That numbers have to be checked in the Lottery array.

If the winner have 3 or 4 numbers of the Lottery array, we win something. If not he loses.
I wrote a code that have the "logic" of what i want, but is giving me a lot of errors...

```
        $player_picket = array($lottery_t_1, $lottery_t_2, $lottery_t_3, $lottery_t_4);
        $lottery_numbers = array(10, 15, 2, 1);
        $prize = 35 * 15;

        $results = [];

         foreach ($player_picket as $numbers) {
             
            $winning = array_intersect($numbers, $lottery_numbers);
            
            $NumbersCount = sizeof($winning); 
             
            if($NumbersCount >= 3) {
                $result[$prize / 2];
            }
            if($NumbersCount == 4) {
                $result[$prize]; 
            }
            if($NumbersCount <= 3) {
                $result[0];
            }
         }            
         
         echo $result;
```

Error Result:

```
Warning: array_intersect(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, int given in D:\xampp\htdocs\lottery.php on line 62

Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in D:\xampp\htdocs\lottery.php on line 64
```

I'm a little suck here.. if someone can give a help.

Comment: The errors are pretty straightforward. Intersection works with two arrays, while you're giving it a number. And then the next function can't use it to get the size since it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use loop, single intersect is enough:

```
$player_picket = array($lottery_t_1, $lottery_t_2, $lottery_t_3, $lottery_t_4);
$lottery_numbers = array(10, 15, 2, 1);
$prize = 35 * 15;

$result = 0;

$winning = array_intersect($numbers, $lottery_numbers);
$NumbersCount = sizeof($winning); 
if ($NumbersCount == 3) {
    $result = $prize / 2;
} else if ($NumbersCount == 4) {
    $result = $prize; 
}
         
echo $result;
```

Comment: lol, of course not. It's a single player. Thank you. My bad.